# How to get replies or quotes on a specific tweet

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am getting the tweets and the corresponding id of that user in an object obj. I want to know why I don't get the other informations like `conversation_id`. I want to use it to get the replies and the quotes. That's the solution that I found in the internet but didn't know how to make  it work.
Does any anyone know to extract the `conversation_id` or any other parameters like `geo.place_id`? I am using tweepy but if anyone has any other solution using another library to get the same result it will be also helpful. Thanks for your help!!!
You can try the code if you create another file config and define your tokens. I can't share mine due to security purposes.

```
import tweepy
import config
users_name = ['derspiegel', 'zeitonline']
tweet_tab = []

def getClient():
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=config.BEARER_TOKEN,
                           consumer_key=config.API_KEY,
                           consumer_secret=config.API_KEY_SECRET,
                           access_token=config.ACCESS_TOKEN,
                           access_token_secret=config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

def searchTweets(client):
    for i in users_name:
        client = getClient()
        user = client.get_user(username=i)
        userId = user.data.id
        tweets = client.get_users_tweets(userId,
                                         expansions=[
                                             'author_id', 'referenced_tweets.id', 'referenced_tweets.id.author_id',
                                             'in_reply_to_user_id', 'attachments.media_keys', 'entities.mentions.username', 'geo.place_id'],
                                         tweet_fields=[
                                             'id', 'text', 'author_id', 'created_at', 'conversation_id', 'entities',
                                             'public_metrics', 'referenced_tweets'
                                         ],
                                         user_fields=[
                                             'id', 'name', 'username', 'created_at', 'description', 'public_metrics',
                                             'verified'
                                         ],
                                         place_fields=['full_name', 'id'],
                                         media_fields=['type', 'url', 'alt_text', 'public_metrics'])
        if not tweets is None and len(tweets) > 0:
            obj = {}
            obj['id'] = userId
            obj['text'] = tweets
            tweet_tab.append(obj)
    return tweet_tab


searchTweets(client)
print("tableau final", tweet_tab)
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you need to put the ids into a list through which the function can iterate. Create the id list and try:

```
def get_tweets_from_timelines():

    tweets_timelines_list = []
    for id in range(0, len(ids), 1):
        one_id = (ids[id:id+1])
        one_id = ' '.join(one_id) 

    for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, id=one_id, max_results=100,
            tweet_fields=['attachments', 'author_id', 'context_annotations', 'created_at', 'entities', \
                'conversation_id', 'possibly_sensitive', 'public_metrics', 'referenced_tweets', \
                 'reply_settings', 'source', 'withheld' ],\
            user_fields=['created_at', 'description', 'entities', 'profile_image_url', 'protected', \
                'public_metrics', 'url', 'verified', 'withheld'],
            expansions=['referenced_tweets.id', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'attachments.media_keys', ],
            media_fields=['preview_image_url'],

                     ): 
            tweets_timelines_list.append(tweet)
    return tweets_timelines_list
```